# Sub menu pushing main menu item next to it

Tags: html, css

i am facing little problem to build dropdown sub-menu, its work find but  the problem is when i hover over its parent item at main menu section then sub-menu pushes the main menu item  next to it and it also pushing background-color below along with it.I want main menu item and background-color to remain at their original place without pushed by sub-menu and sub-menu show  below main menu.So if anybody solve this problem then i will grateful to you guys.Here is the source code take a look:-

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Dropdown</title>
<style>
 body {
   margin: 0;
 }

 .navbar {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #333;
 }


 .navbar-list a {
   float: left;
   padding: 14px 15px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
 }

 /* courses section*/
 .drop-course {
   float: left;
   margin: 14px 0 0 15px;
 }

 .course-btn {
   border: none;
   background-color: inherit;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 17px;
 }

 .courses-list a {
   float: none;
   display: block;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-align: left;
 }

 .courses-list {
   display: none;
   margin-top: 20px;
   background-color: #333;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   color: #fff;
 }

 .drop-course:hover .courses-list {
   display: block;
 }

 /* extra section */
 .drop-extra {
   float: left;
   margin: 14px 0 0 15px;
 }

 .extra-btn {
   border: none;
   background-color: inherit;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 17px;
 }

 .extra-content a {
   float: none;
   display: block;
   margn-top: 8px;
   padding: 5px;
 }

 .extra-content {
   display: none;
   background-color: inherit;
   color: #fff;
 }

 .drop-extra:hover .extra-content {
   display: block;
 }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<!--Navigation Section-->
<div class="navbar">

 <div class="navbar-list">
   <a href="#">Home</a>
   <a href="#">Notice</a>

   <div class="drop-course">
     <button class="course-btn">Courses</button>
     <div class="courses-list">
       <a href="#">Web Development</a>
       <a href="#">Android Development</a>
       <a href="#">ios Development</a>
     </div>
   </div>

   <a href="#">Admissions</a>

   <div class="drop-extra">
     <button class="extra-btn">extra</button>
     <div class="extra-content">
       <a href="#">link1</a>
       <a href="#">link2</a>
     </div>
   </div>

 </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a few tweaks to your code. The position CSS property sets how an element is positioned in a document. Use this link to learn about positions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Dropdown</title>
<style>
 body {
   margin: 0;
 }

 .navbar {
   background-color: #333;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
 }


 .navbar-list a {
   float: left;
   padding: 14px 15px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
 }

 /* courses section*/
 .drop-course {
   float: left;
   margin: 14px 0 0 15px;
 }

 .course-btn {
   border: none;
   background-color: inherit;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 17px;
 }

 .courses-list a {
   float: none;
   display: block;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-align: left;
 }

 .courses-list {
   display: none;
   margin-top: 20px;
   background-color: #333;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   color: #fff;
 }

 .drop-course:hover .courses-list {
   display: block;
 }

 /* extra section */
 .drop-extra {
   float: left;
   margin: 14px 0 0 15px;
 }

 .extra-btn {
   border: none;
   background-color: inherit;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 17px;
 }

 .extra-content a {
   float: none;
   display: block;
   margn-top: 8px;
   padding: 5px;
 }

 .extra-content {
   display: none;
   background-color: inherit;
   color: #fff;
 }

 .drop-extra:hover .extra-content {
   display: block;
 }

 .drop-container{
   position: relative;
 }
 .drop-list{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<!--Navigation Section-->
<div class="navbar">

 <div class="navbar-list">
   <a href="#">Home</a>
   <a href="#">Notice</a>

   <div class="drop-course drop-container">
     <button class="course-btn">Courses</button>
     <div class="courses-list drop-list">
       <a href="#">Web Development</a>
       <a href="#">Android Development</a>
       <a href="#">ios Development</a>
     </div>
   </div>

   <a href="#">Admissions</a>

   <div class="drop-course drop-container">
     <button class="course-btn">extra</button>
     <div class="courses-list drop-list">
       <a href="#">link1</a>
       <a href="#">link2</a>
     </div>
   </div>

 </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas , I got it. It's about position property.